# Android studio showing error while uploading the app to device via USB

Tags: android-studio

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try running gradle with --info or --debug option to get more log output? ...or run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you shouldn't use app level build.gradle file's dependencies. Read the comment there. That section is not for libraries. You must open your app level build.gradle file and view dependencies section there. And you should use pdf viewer library there correctly. Use it like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:AndroidPdfViewer:2.0.0'
}
```

And add this to your build.gradle files:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your build.gradle where you might be using Signing configs keys but it's not fetched properly. Also check your buildTypes.